# Attempting to log in using Google account in cfoauth tag

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am trying to login using the `<cfoauth>` tag, but am not able to do so. It is showing

> Error: invalid_request

Below is my code.

```
<cfoauth
type = "google"
clientid = "*****************es7t0r6qc"
secretkey = "**************tSF97WncM5ix9jtvD200"
result = "result"
scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
redirecturi = "http://192.168.9.126:8088/bootstrap-blog-template/tpl/cfoauth.cfm"
>
```

Please help.

Comment: You really need to give us some more details. Show us the complete error message and stack trace if available. Monitor the network traffic and show us the request and response data.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be related to `redirecturi`. You need to provide an existing and valid URL of the page on which you want to redirect to after authentication.

For example if local URL of the page you are testing the code is http://localhost:8500/cfbuster/login.cfm , then `redirecturi` can be same page i.e. http://localhost:8500/cfbuster/login.cfm or another page http://localhost:8500/cfbuster/doLogin.cfm.

Apart from this, the `redirecturi` you wish to set, should be saved in **Google Developers Consele >> API Manager >> Credentials** screen under `Authorized redirect URIs`. In my case it is http://localhost:8500/cfbuster/test.cfm

[image]

In case the `redirecturi` passed is non existing or not saved in the API `Authorized redirect URIs` screen we get following error message:

[image]

**Note 1**: The `redirecturi` Must have a protocol. Cannot contain URL fragments or relative paths. Cannot be a public IP address.

**Note 2**: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login is the recommended login scope. The https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me scope is not recommended as a login scope because, for users who have not upgraded to Google+, it does not return the user's name or email address.